# How do I display three images in a row given that I am using bootstrap?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, model

I have an image model and each image has related entries, which are also images. I want to display the related three entries in a row depending on how many of them there are. I am using bootstrap.

This is what I have written so far:

```
<% @image.related_entries.each.in_groups_of(3, false).each_with_index do |entry_row, i| 
  <div class="row_thumbnails">
   # In row 1 I want 3 entries(images displayed in thumbnail look)
   </div>

<%end%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [each_slice](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_slice)

```
<% @image.related_entries.each_slice(3) do |related_img_slice|
  <div class="row">
    <% related_img_slice.each do |related_img|
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <%= image_tag(related_img.location) %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Place the images in divs that use bootstraps column classes. A bootstrap container is 12 columns wide, so you can place them in the class `col-md-4` which will total 12 for every 3 images. [Info on the bootstrap grid system.](http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#predefined-classes)

Comment: You are close. But how would you write that dynamically given that the number of related items can vary ?

Comment: On the first image start a row, then every 3rd image close the row and start a new one. Make sure you have logic to properly close out the rows on the last image - i.e. if it is not % 3 close the row.

Comment: How do you write it Patrick, with what I have already provided ?

Comment: Sorry, not familiar with Ruby so can't give you a exact code snippet to paste in - I was just speaking to how to get bootstrap to do it. Should just be a simple loop to iterate through your images and a few if statements to handle when to write the opening and closing row tags.